# Keep jumping till a cycle

Tags: code-golf, number

## Objective

You're on a nonempty list of integers that wraps around. You start at the leftmost entry of the list, and keep jumping to the right to the amount of the integer entry you're at.

Eventually, you'll end up in a cycle. The objective is to output the length of this cycle.

## I/O format

Provided that the inputted list has \$n\$ entries, each entry \$m\$ is assumed to satisfy \$0 \leq m < n\$. Otherwise flexible.

## Examples

```
Input, Output
[0], 1
[0, 1, 2], 1
[1, 0, 2], 1
[1, 1, 2], 2
[2, 2, 2, 2], 2
[2, 3, 2, 1], 2
[3, 3, 3, 2], 3
[1, 1, 1, 1], 4
```

## Worked Example

```
[1, 2, 3, 2]
 ^
[1, 2, 3, 2]
    ^
[1, 2, 3, 2]
          ^
[1, 2, 3, 2]
    ^
Cycle detected; halt. The output is: 2.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ėṙ`ḢṪƊÐḶL
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list of integers and yields the cycle length.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///ItIc7ZyY83LHo4c5Vx7oOT3i4Y5vP/6OTHu6coXO4PetRwxwFWzuFRw1zNSP//4@ONojV4VKINtBRMNRRMAKzgQwDJDZc3AjIgCAY1xjMNQRzjcFcY1SNhhDZWAA)**

#### How?

Keep a record of the original indices along with their jump-values and repeatedly rotate this left by its first jump-value to find the cycle and output its length.

The implementation actually rotates by all indices and jump-values then picks out the one we want (rotated by first jump-value).

```
Ėṙ`ḢṪƊÐḶL - Link: list of integers, Jumps
Ė         - enumerate  -> [[1, jump1], [2, jump2], ...]
      ÐḶ  - start with that and collect up while distinct then yield loop, applying:
     Ɗ    -   last three links as a monad - f(Current):
  `       -     use as both arguments of:
 ṙ        -       rotate {Current} left by {Current} (vectorises)
   Ḣ      -     head -> rotations by the first index and first jump
    Ṫ     -     tail -> rotation by the first jump
        L - length
```

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 65 bytes

```r
\(a){while(!(T=(T+a[+T]-1)%%sum(a|1)+1)%in%F)F=c(T,F)
match(T,F)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY3HWM0EjWryzMyc1I1FDVCbDVCtBOjtUNidQ01VVWLS3M1EmsMNbWBnMw8VTdNN9tkjRAdN02u3MSS5AwwsxZq0NQ0jWQNA01NBWUFQy4wW0fBUEfBCEkEyDXAEIGrMQKLGAG5EIQqaAwWNEQSNAYLGsNUGiMZaAhTaQJx3IIFEBoA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 62 bytes

*-4 bytes, thanks to loopy walt*

```python
lambda L,i=0:len({*[i:=(i+L[i])%len(L)for _ in 2*L][len(L):]})
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY37XISc5NSEhV8dDJtDaxyUvM0qrWiM61sNTK1faIzYzVVQUI-mmn5RQrxCpl5CkZaPrHREDGr2FpNqCkPCooy80o00jSiDWI1NZV1FAy5ECJAno6CEYY4UNAAhzhCvRFC3AjIgyBsUsZgKUMMKWOwlDFclzG6RYZwXSZYpGDegfhzwQIIDQA)

### Explanation

1. compute list of first `2*len(L)` jumps
2. find the number of unique indices in the last `len(l)` jumps

---

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 93 bytes

```python
lambda l,i=0,s=[0]:1+len([(s:=s+[i:=j])for _ in l if(j:=(i+l[i])%len(l))not in s])-s.index(j)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dY_dCoIwFIDve4pBBBvOUNdFDPYka4Sho8ma4hbUs3QjRL1Tdz1KU0shCw4czvedH87lXp3dvjTNVbLN7ehkuH4InR52WQo0VizClvFI0DjQuYEcWspswBVlhUCyrMEWKAM0UBIWlEEVaK4EWrS9GiFTulZbgUK7VCbLT7BA7yPPqlbGQQn9doTmGMSzkfgKg2TCPYz-8LE_GXniqz5-KdKpeKJIp8gwRb4PxcPU6of6vNP_2TR9fgE)

### Explanation

1. go through the first `len(l)` jumps, stop if a duplicate is found
2. return the (1-based) index of the duplicate element in the list of indices counted from the end of the list

Comment: A "pure" walrus right before `for` in a comprehension doesn't need parentheses. And you can save another [2](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY37XISc5NSEhV8dDJtDaxyUvM0qrWiM61sNTK1faIzYzVVQUI-mmn5RQrxCpl5CkZaPrHREDGr2FpNqCkPCooy80o00jSiDWI1NZV1FAy5ECJAno6CEYY4UNAAhzhCvRFC3AjIgyBsUsZgKUMMKWOwlDFclzG6RYZwXSZYpGDegfhzwQIIDQA)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 56 bytes

```javascript
a=>(g=t=>t-(a[i=(i+a[i|0])%a.length]||=t++)||g(t))(i=.5)
```

```js
f=

a=>(g=t=>t-(a[i=(i+a[i|0])%a.length]||=t++)||g(t))(i=.5)


t = `
[0], 1
[0, 1, 2], 1
[1, 0, 2], 1
[1, 1, 2], 2
[2, 2, 2, 2], 2
[2, 3, 2, 1], 2
[3, 3, 3, 2], 3
[1, 1, 1, 1], 4
`.trim().split('\n').map(l => JSON.parse(`[${l}]`));
t.forEach(([i, e]) => {
  console.log(f([...i]) == e, f([...i]))
});
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
+J,1ị@\ÐḶL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/bS8fw4e5uh5jDEx7u2Obz/3C77aGlRvqR//9Hc0UbxOooGOoAaRClYATlAZkGKDyonBGQZwSiwAghYAwWMIQKGIMFjCEqjOEGGEJUmOhwxQIA)

*-1 [thanks to Bubbler](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64427282#64427282)*

```
+J            Add every jump number to its 1-index.
  ,1          Pair that with 1.
       ÐḶ     Loop while unique then extract the cycle:
      \       scan by
    ị@        modular 1-index right into left.
      \ÐḶ     (Dyadic ÐḶ doesn't reuse the right argument.)
         L    Take the length of the cycle.
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 54 bytes

```javascript
f=(a,i=j=0)=>j-a[~i]||f(a,(i+a[i])%a.length,a[~i]=j++)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc5NCsMgEAXgfU/hpqBoftRu7UXExZDGVBEtTegq9Oo2pJTQUOkwq3kfj/HwgLG7u9tUxXTpc7YKA3PKq5aos69AP52ZZ7scsaOgnSFHqEMfh@nK1lB5SknuUhxT6OuQBmyxbg36DCGoaRA/7AVDnCFhymKJ27/iu0PshVji95qykKvgJSFXIbcO@fsPvnWc8gs)

---

## JavaScript (ES12), 52 bytes

-2 bytes by using nullish coalescing assignment, as suggested by [@tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44718/tsh).

```javascript
f=(a,i=j=0)=>j-(a[~i]??=j++)||f(a,(i+a[i])%a.length)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kLz8ldcGCpaUlaboWN03SbDUSdTJts2wNNG3tsnQ1EqPrMmPt7W2ztLU1a2rSgJIamdqJ0ZmxmqqJejmpeeklGZoQvbcY-ZPz84rzc1L1cvLTNdI0og1iFWBAU1NBX1_BkAtdhY6CoY6CUSxuFUBpA4IqUM0wQldhBJSGoFjcKozBKgxxqTAGqzBGmGGM3R2GCDNMIOECC1sA)

Comment: 52: `f=(a,i=j=0)=>j-(a[~i]??=j++)||f(a,(i+a[i])%a.length)`

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 99 bytes

```python
lambda x,y=0,z={}:next(i-z[y]for i in range(len(x)+1)if y in z or[z:=z|{y:i},y:=(y+x[y])%len(x)]*0)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XVDtasMgFGV_fYpLYKCrHfnYjyH4JGkoLjWbkJqgdsR0fZL9CYztnbanmaldWyZy9Zxzj_de37967146PX00fPW5c83y8btuxfZpI2Cgnqd05PsD03JwWC3H0ldNZ0CB0mCEfpa4lRoPZJER1YCf6RE6U46Mj297z9SBesaxXwzBSW5jcnWXkljq5wY5ad26FlZa4FvRY_kqWpokSZlWFDJUpiFSyCMIt_QanJQclXmIcZ9xccRZxMURF1Ev_sxZ1B9CvXvbt8rhZKUTQhCapzy3RkEOvayd3KyNtLvWzXNeGmcIwuqN0g5feXDMZby5sIRQiDTn_948fck0xfMX)

Comment: `lambda x,z={},y=0:next(i-z[y]for i in range(len(x)+1)if z.get(y,-1)+1or((z:=z|{y:i})and(y:=(y+x[y])%len(x))&0))`?

Comment: @UndoneStudios I thought I couldn't because mutable default arguments but you are correct I can since I overwrite it every time

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 16 bytes

```
0λIā<+sè}Igô1èÙg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f4NxuzyONNtrFh1fUeqYf3mJ4eMXhmen//0cb6yhAkFEsAA)

Comment: Alternative 16-byter based on _bsoelch_'s first Python answer: [`g·0λ£Iā<+sè}Rćk>`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8//dB2g3O7Dy32PNJoo118eEVt0JH2bLv//6ONdRQgyCgWAA). I have the feeling this challenge can be done shorter in 05AB1E though, but haven't found anything yet.

Comment: Found a 13-byter: `.āIv¬н._D})Ùg` - [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/vSONlWWH1lzYqxfvUqt5eGb6f53/0dEGsTrRBjqGOkZA2lDHAEpD@EY6YAhmGQNZhkCWsQ4IwlQZgsWAqsFisQA).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen The 13-byter fails on `[1, 1, 0, 2]` — it counts the warmup, if it's more than one element.

Comment: Ah. I already kinda had my doubts on the 13-byter despite it giving the correct results for all test cases. :( I assume adding a `¦` before the uniquify and an `û` before the `v` won't be enough either? It does fix that `[1,1,0,2]` without breaking the other test cases: [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/vSONlYd3lx1ac2GvXrxLreahZYdnpv/X@R8dbRCrE22gY6hjBKQNdQygNIRvpAOGYJYxkGUIZBnrgCBMlSFYDKgaSQxkRiwA). Although a -1 byte save compared to your current solution isn't as substantially as I had hoped.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Adding `¦` before the uniquify only fixed the problem for length 2 warmup, `[1,1,1,0]` still fails. The number of elements you remove has to be at least n-2. It does feel like there should be a shorter solution, but I can't find it

Answer (score 2):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), <s>41 34 31 30</s> 29 bytes

```
##@~.@}.0]F:.(#@[|]+{~)2###,:
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FNVUtFK8NYM0UrS3V1LiU99TQFWysFdQUdBQMFKyDW1VNwDvJxW1pakqZrsVdZ2aFOz6FWzyDWzUpPQ9khuiZWu7pO00hZWVnHCqLm5iNNrtTkjHyFNAUDOEPBUMEIxjEEcpE4SDJGEIjgGgOxIYxrDIYoOg1BshWZJUCXRxvE6gB50QZAUkfBCMIBsgyQOVAZI65oIyAJQXC-MZhvCOEbg_nGEHljmGZDiLwJxKcLFkBoAA)

*-3 thanks to a nice observation by ovs: If you run the simulation 2*n times, as I was, you can ensure you get only the cyclic elements by removing the first `n`*

*I also shaved another byte off by applying a trick from another of ovs's suggestion*

This is a combination of two suggestions from ovs, using `F:.` for folding.

### [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), <s>41 34 31</s> 30 bytes, saved for a new J trick

```
##@~.@}.<@+:@#@[(#@[|]+{~^:)&0
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fZHBSgMxEIbxuk8xNdhNuttskhWxYReCQk_iwWtIRaSL9eKlgrA1L-JlPfgAvoDvoU_jNOnW9VKSmczH_88kkLf3x-77ZDbS0p2N9CxNk2OeNlBrSCEHARpjyuHy5mr-8bxupudfhBjPzSuvTKYNMZZibFzW-oVmYxFNP0efLLm-4HDYHCyScKuprAgruN_rbKGpqswEuTdaHYZR4mWFTUvODrkpdRnPeAF8guqd9sxQVxeeGLfJ2Iobshta4cMEdTltfavZdpKrxwQvcljfeoIXBPfy_uEJGhD7AiSoHiTiAAaKiusPSwzZYxnWv065VV9Wa_wKK1yOZAXmHFQErMQQdopKrMIc957LwDJyGbiMetk3y6ifxp_runj-Ag)

- `<@+:@#@[(#@[|]+{~^:)&0` Simulate the jumps 2*n times.  For J lang enthusiasts, we are using a partially applied conjunction as an adverb here: `(#@[|]+{~^:)` -- it modifies the verb `<@+:@#@[`, and is equivalent to the standard form `(#@[|]+{~)^:(<@+:@#@[)`.  It is acting here as a syntactic trick that allows us to save to some parens.
- `##@~.@}.` Now remove the first n elements (ensuring we only have cyclic elements left), and take the count of the uniq

Comment: You could go for an explicit function for -1 or use `F:.`: for [32 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fZHBSgMxEIbxuk8xdbCbdLfZJCtiwy4EhZ7Eg9clikgX68VLBWFLHsEX8LIefKj6NE6TblsvMpnJfPx_JpB8fr30m7PZyCh3MTKzNE1ORdpCbSCFHCQYyqmA67ub-ffbqp1ebkChUBWVxtTSzY1gaJu1yzrPNSLmJvp-Tj54cnslIDiZqpAXwh-894bpyk6I-VgGY2PQemEZ-jB-Ifh_bsZcJjJRgJiQ-mg8t8zVhUfr1hlfCou7oZWxKJnLWec7w7eTXD1GushR_-CRLgjuxdPzK7Qg9w0o0AMowiM4UnSMA5aUasAyxJ-Taqu-L1f01I10OVEjqeagI1Anj2Gn6KTRVOPacxlYRS4Dl1Evh8Mq6ufxW_o-7r8)

Comment: And there is another 32 similar to Jonathan Allan's Jelly answer: `{{#~.<@#g#(g=.{.@,|.]^:)y,./:y}}`

Comment: [31 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fZHNSgMxEMfxuk8xNdhNuttsPkRs2IWg4Ek8eA1RRLpYL14qCFvzCL6Al_Xgc_gc-jROk26tB2Uyk_nxnw9IXt_u-8-D2chIfzQyszzP9nneQmMghxIEGPQph9PL87P3x2U7Pf4gxAZunzkl1q180QV2Zaiq7QSZjUWq-tp7YdnFCQdJuDNU1oRVPPzREgudiXMpCbLGpjln_1VT6gte8Ar4BNUbE5ilvqkCsX5VsAW3ZDO0NpYI6kvahc6w9STfjAku8phfB4ILYvX89u4BWhDbBCSoASTiDuwoKtkPanQ5oI72q1Ou1afFEh_aCV8iOYGxBJUAM7ELG0VlTmFMZ8s6skysI-uk66FZJv0wfUvfp_sb)

Comment: @ovs tyvm.  i have a theory that solutions using `F:.` can never be the shortest golf, which was in jeopardy for a moment, but you saved it.

Comment: I think you should look a bit closer at the two suggestions ;) (You might be able to combine them)

Comment: Also I really think it has it's niche in golfing. If you have a scan/fold that requires a seed value of a different type than the elements of the array, it will very likely be shorter than `/` or `\\`. Also linear-time scans can be nice. (FWIW I'm using variants on three holes on code.golf)

Comment: @ovs Interesting!  I will take another look then.

Comment: @ovs Shaved off another byte by applying your conjunction-as-adverb trick, which I don't think I've used before.  Feels like there's probably a few more bytes to be found somewhere....

Comment: @ovs, 29 using `F:.` combining your suggestions.  My theory falls.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 12 bytes

```
ẏYd‡hǓ~↲t$↲L
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJ+IiwiIiwi4bqPWWTigKFox5N+4oaydCTihrJMIiwiIiwiWzBdID0+IDFcblswLCAxLCAyXSA9PiAxXG5bMSwgMCwgMl0gPT4gMVxuWzEsIDEsIDJdID0+IDJcblsyLCAyLCAyLCAyXSA9PiAyXG5bMiwgMywgMiwgMV0gPT4gMlxuWzMsIDMsIDMsIDJdID0+IDNcblsxLCAxLCAxLCAxXSA9PiA0Il0=)

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 95 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY49r8IwDEX39yv8BiRbhIqPrVWQGJFADIgJMZiSQlAI4ER8Vf3tJXS4tnyOhxtKdtxe92dTRliy9VD/ARxMBZd0IMsx5DAT4fd2HcX6445y2HgbQXefALdEo/NY4cKGiGM1UWM1IqJkm5QHO6jyn9vOfdzpaZqgW6en9YMFRTFpXJt7Z5HUkIrnyTqD/5KVVx9TjYBMVEve11ywRu67H@i5LNiPaQrp9kAy6w/mtaqSbNqm/QI)

```scala
l=>{var(r,a)=(Seq[Int](),0);while(!r.contains(a)){r:+=a;a=(a+l(a))%l.size};r.size-r.indexOf(a)}
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY49b8IwEIZ3fsXbAeksAmrTLRIDIxKoQ9Up6nANDhgZg85WC63y29OLFWU53/vhRxcb9tz316@zbRL27AL@ZsDBtrioIJZjrLAR4Uf9nsSF46ep8BFcwjo3gZu6yQdqaediorJ4LcrixRijaTcbYS35CkNeb0MaEPpMhG8WiKopJzP5rP5zVj8n5y3oSVbNNSQ9LhIbMyKQAYJqAR6N4ScxFvC5N4dfRfdrc9rlKdnAUhcXDvb@1mozX931/T8)

```scala
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(f(List(2,3,2,1)))
  }

  def f(l: List[Int]): Int = {
    var r = List[Int]()
    var a = 0
    while (!r.contains(a)) {
      r = r :+ a
      a = (a + l(a)) % l.size
    }
    r.size - r.indexOf(a)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 62 bytes

```ruby
->l{*r=a=0;1while r!=r|=[a=(a+l[a])%l.size];r.size-r.index(a)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6nWqvINtHWwNqwPCMzJ1WhSNG2qMY2OtFWI1E7JzoxVlM1R684syo11roITOsW6WXmpaRWaCRq1v4vUEiLjjbSMdYx0jGMjf0PAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 29 bytes

```
ＵＭθ⁺ικ⊞υ⁰Ｆ⁺θθ⊞υ§θ↨υ⁰Ｉ⊕⌕Φ⮌υκ⊟υ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU3JCoMwFLz3K97xBVLocvTUCgUPgvQqHkJ8xdCYaBbp36eJpXMYhlkYOQknrdAptWKp7TwLM@LKodPRo@LwZqw6dNFPGDmcsn5ZB7inubUyBv/wFhoz0qfYd@Hp19/XTpmAtfABGyMdzWQCjfhQppAO5PBJG7myYeUxv9sl64Iqpb4/c7hwuGYehnTc9Bc) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Port of @bsoelch's Python answer.

```
ＵＭθ⁺ικ
```

Add the index to each element to give its (cyclic) destination index.

```
⊞υ⁰
```

Start on the leftmost index.

```
Ｆ⁺θθ
```

Repeat enough times to guarantee a cycle.

```
⊞υ§θ↨υ⁰
```

Get the next index.

```
Ｉ⊕⌕Φ⮌υκ⊟υ
```

Find the length of the cycle.